# Angular11 Renderer seStyle is not working

Tags: angular

Initial
this.renderer.setElementStyle(buttonContainer, 'marginTop', '0px');

After Render2
this.renderer.setStyle(buttonContainer, 'marginTop', '0px');

SetStyle is not setting the style.

Please help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you have to import element ref from @angular/core .  in your constructor:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

    

this.render.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement('buttonContainer'), 'marginTop', '0px')
```